Understanding the concept of random variable
For example, imagine picking a random real number $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$ (with uniform distribution). Then the sample space is $\Bbb R$. So, given some $\omega\in\Bbb R$, what does $X(\omega)$ represent? Is $X$ defined as $X(\omega)=\omega$? If so, why do we need $X$ in the first place?

The sample space does not need to be $\mathbb R$.  Suppose your problem was more complicated: perhaps $N$ is a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$, and seeing $N$ you wanted $Y$ to be the sum of $N$ i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ and $\mathbf X=(N,Y)$.  Then $N$ and $Y$ and $\mathbf X$  would each be a random variable and you would want them to be $N(\omega), Y(\omega), \mathbf X(\omega)$ with an observation of them to correspond to a single $\omega \in \Omega$.  ...

... This would be likely to make $\Omega$ more complicated than $\mathbb R$, and it would certainly prevent $N(\omega) =\omega, Y(\omega)=\omega, \mathbf X(\omega)=\omega$ simultaneously.

$X$ is just a (measurable) function on $\Omega$. For example, $\sin$ is a random variable on your space.

Yes, as you have observed,  a heck of a lot of the time when you have a continuous random variable the sample space isn't even specified, and you're just given a p.d.f. And in these cases we might as well use your "trivial" instantiation, where $X(\omega) =\omega$. One could do it other ways, but you wouldn't really gain anything.
There are a few reasons why we have the sample space and random variable formalism. Sometimes the sample space is what's easiest to describe and so comes first. It also makes it easier to treat both the discrete and the continuous cases with a single theory. And, as described in the comments, sometimes we want to have multiple different random variables associated with the same sample space.
